# Make background color extend into overflow area

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

If the total *content height* of the parent is 10,000px but the `overflow: auto` element is *rendered* with a height of 700px how do I force the `aside` child element to dynamically render as 10,000px *instead* of the default 700px? You can see the white background the moment you begin to scroll [the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4m1L2tLh/).

- May not add any more elements (`::after` and `::before` are acceptable though).
- The `aside` element must have it's content scroll with `main` element's content via the `#body` element (no `position: fixed;`).
- The `aside` element must have it's `background-color` stretch from the very top at 0px to the very bottom (e.g. 5,000px or 10,000px) far *below* the initial visible fold.
- The `aside` element must not have it's own `overflow: auto;`.
- Dynamic (for the lesser knowledged) implies we can *not* set a static `height`, e.g. `height: 10000px` as we will *not* know what the rendered height will be.

In my example the moment you begin to scroll the green `background-color` ends, I want to make the `aside` element stretch all the way to the content bottom.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Overflow Flex Box Issue</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

aside
{
 background-color: #afa;
 order: 2;
 width: 20%;
}

body
{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
}

body > header
{
 align-self: stretch;
 background-color: #faa;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 min-height: 56px;
 order: 1;
}

body > footer
{
 align-self: auto;
 background-color: #aaf;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 min-height: 36px;
 order: 2;
}

html {height: 100%;}

main
{
 background-color: #cfc;
 order: 1;
 width: 80%;
}

#body
{
 display: flex;
 order: 2;
 overflow: auto;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="body">
<main>
<article>
<p>article</p>
<p>article</p>
<p>article</p>
<div style="height: 10000px;">10,000px</div>
</article>
</main>
<aside><p>&#60;aside&#62;, 100% height only of visible area, it <em>should</em> be <em>100% of total parent height</em>.</p></aside>
</div>

<header>The body &#62; header element; element 2, order: 1;.</header>
<footer>The body &#62; footer element; element 3, order: 3;.</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

Barring absolute positioning, this is not possible with CSS. You'll need to use JavaScript.

Here's the problem:

### Part I: `background-color`

You have no height defined for the content element (`#body`).

This means that the height is content-driven.

**A background color will only cover the width and height of the element.** You can see this in your demo. As soon as the scrolling begins, the background color ends. That's because the overflow area is outside the width / height area of the element.

*From the spec:*

> [**14.2 The
>   background**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/colors.html#background)
>
> Authors may specify the background of an element (i.e., its rendering
>   surface) as either a color or an image. In terms of the [box
>   model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#box-model), "background"
>   refers to the background of the `content`, `padding` and `border`
>   areas.

So CSS background properties are designed to cover an area up to the borders of the element. They do not cover the margin area. They do not overflow.

---

### Part II: `overflow`

This is another reason for the truncated  background color.

**The `overflow` property only applies to content.** It has nothing to do with backgrounds.

*From the spec:*

> [**11.1.1 Overflow: the `overflow`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#overflow)
>
> This property specifies whether content of a block container element
>   is clipped when it overflows the element's box.

---

With these two obstacles standing in the way, CSS is not useful in solving this problem (except for possible hacks). The only way to make a background color fill the entire length of a dynamically-sized container would be with a script.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this meets all of your criteria, but how about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4m1L2tLh/1/) solution?   Simply wrapping the parent div in a container and setting the overflow-y to auto like so should do the trick:

```
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: The exact effect but, no, can *not* add additional elements but I will see if I can adjust what elements do exist...

Comment: Works as intended in sceanrios where you can add a wrapping div @Belder

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* the way I intended to achieve the result as I would like to set `background-image` on the `#body` in many cases though it may be acceptable subjective to how I handle things, here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4m1L2tLh/2/). I'm certain that this issue will be resolved at some point in the future.

```css
#body
{
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cfc 0%, #cfc 79%, #afa calc(79% + 4px), #afa 100%);
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Overflow Flexbox Issue</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; scroll-behavior: smooth;}

aside
{
 background-color: ;
 order: 2;
 width: 20%;
}

body
{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

body > header
{
 align-self: stretch;
 background-color: #faa;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 min-height: 56px;
 order: 1;
}

body > footer
{
 align-self: auto;
 background-color: #aaf;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 min-height: 36px;
 order: 2;
}

html {height: 100%;}

main
{
 order: 1;
 width: 80%;
}

#body
{
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cfc 0%, #cfc 79%, #afa calc(79% + 4px), #afa 100%);
 display: flex;
 order: 2;
 overflow: auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="body">
<main>
<article>
<p>article</p>
<p>article</p>
<p>article</p>
<div style="height: 10000px;">10,000px</div>
</article>
</main>
<aside><p>&#60;aside&#62;, 100% height only of visible area, it <em>should</em> be <em>100% of total parent height</em>.</p></aside>
</div>

<header>The body &#62; header element; element 2, order: 1;.</header>
<footer>The body &#62; footer element; element 3, order: 3;.</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's a pretty simple solution with just CSS and without touching the markup.

- `display:table-cell` for the `aside` and the `main`
- omit the display flex on the `#body`

Here's a fully functional snippet:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Overflow Flex Box Issue</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

aside
{
 background-color: #afa;
 order: 2;
 width: 20%;
  display: table-cell;
}

body
{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
}

body > header
{
 align-self: stretch;
 background-color: #faa;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 min-height: 56px;
 order: 1;
}

body > footer
{
 align-self: auto;
 background-color: #aaf;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 min-height: 36px;
 order: 2;
}

html {height: 100%;}

main
{
 background-color: #cfc;
 order: 1;
 width: 80%;
 display: table-cell;
}

#body
{
 order: 2;
 overflow: auto;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="body">
<main>
<article>
<p>article</p>
<p>article</p>
<p>article</p>
<div style="height: 10000px;">10,000px</div>
</article>
</main>
<aside><p>&#60;aside&#62;, 100% height only of visible area, it <em>should</em> be <em>100% of total parent height</em>.</p></aside>
</div>

<header>The body &#62; header element; element 2, order: 1;.</header>
<footer>The body &#62; footer element; element 3, order: 3;.</footer>

</body>
</html>
```