# Make flex container width grow as its children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is simplified layout:

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cell">
      <input type="text" class="contact"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is simplified CSS:

```
.root {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 300px;

}

.container {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
}

.cell {
  background-color: black;
  height: 30px;
}

.contact {
  width: 400px;
}
```

This is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/rnky40mo/1/).

It is somewhat unexpected to me that the `container` width isn't the same as it is required by its child and rather is as limited by the `root` `div`. You can see in this jsFiddle that red area (root `div`) isn't filled with the green `container` `div`.

Could someone explain why `flex` container width doesn't grow as its children and how to fix that?

Comment: @LGSon: Everything looks great, accepted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Block element grows to its parent width, inline grows with its content.

A great and more in-depth explanation can be found here:

- [Make background color extend into overflow area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497031/make-background-color-extend-into-overflow-area/45497692#45497692)

---

Change to `inline-flex` and you get the expected result.

```css
.root {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 300px;
  
}

.container {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-flex;                /*  changed  */
  height: 50px;
}

.cell {
  background-color: black;
  height: 30px;
}

.contact {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cell">
      <input type="text" class="contact">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The link appears to work, but I don't see what relevance it has to this article, nor does it have the same title as the link suggests?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh Ahh, now I see, it changes the URL completely when clicked on. Thanks, I will flag that for moderation and see what they say.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh Someone changed the title of that older question. I now updated the link to one of its answer, which talks about a block elements background color, which have the similar effect on overflowed child block elements, hence its description is of value for this answer of mine as well.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you also want the container to never shrink below its parent size (i.e. when its children are smaller), you need to use `min-width: 100%`. Alternatively, you can replace both the inline display and the `min-width` with the new `min-width: min-content`. http://jsbin.com/xumeqik/2/edit?html,css,output