# Flex layout with fixed and non-fixed height pages

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a website with two kinds of pages:

- no page scroll, children handle their scroll (https://codepen.io/Zephir77167/pen/mzymwO?editors=1100)
- page scroll, children don't handle their scroll (https://codepen.io/Zephir77167/pen/ePmWja?editors=1100)

The first example works because of this CSS:

```
.root {
  height: 100%;
  /* min-height: 100%; */
}
```

The second example works because of this CSS:

```
.root {
  /* height: 100%; */
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Apart from the `.root` class, the code is exactly the same. I would like to have the same `.root` code for both layouts.

This was my initial workaround: https://codepen.io/Zephir77167/pen/BqyMxw?editors=1100

```
.columns {
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
}
```

but `vh` doesn't work well on Chrome Android and Safari iOS.

Some restrictions :

- can't use `vh`
- can't use javascript
- `html`, `body`, `.root`, `.layout`, `.content` CSS should be the same for both layouts, and both should work as before

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45497031/3597276

Comment: Thanks for trying to explain the problem in more detail but there are still unclear sides. Do you want to have identical codes but each performs slightly differently? And your codes are not same even when .root part is excluded. As I see the first codepen works correctly but the problem is with the second one.  Am I correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems it still isn't clear. Both codepens display as expected, but currently they do not share the same code. I would need the base classes to be the same

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.root {
  height: 100%;
}

.layout {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.navbar-space {
  height: 60px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
}

.gap {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.left-column,
.right-column {
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.header,
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.non-scrollable {
  overflow-y: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <div class="navbar-space"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="left-column">
          <div class="header">
            Column A
            <hr />
          </div>
          <div class="non-scrollable">
            Quid? qui se etiam nunc subsidiis patrimonii aut amicorum liberalitate sustentant, hos perire patiemur? An, si qui frui publico non potuit per hostem, hic tegitur ipsa lege censoria; quem is frui non sinit, qui est, etiamsi non appellatur, hostis, huic ferri auxilium non oportet? Retinete igitur in provincia diutius eum, qui de sociis cum hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.

Quam ob rem id primum videamus, si placet, quatenus amor in amicitia progredi debeat. Numne, si Coriolanus habuit amicos, ferre contra patriam arma illi cum Coriolano debuerunt? num Vecellinum amici regnum adpetentem, num Maelium debuerunt iuvare?

Vita est illis semper in fuga uxoresque mercenariae conductae ad tempus ex pacto atque, ut sit species matrimonii, dotis nomine futura coniunx hastam et tabernaculum offert marito, post statum diem si id elegerit discessura, et incredibile est quo ardore apud eos in venerem uterque solvitur sexus.

Quibus ita sceleste patratis Paulus cruore perfusus reversusque ad principis castra multos coopertos paene catenis adduxit in squalorem deiectos atque maestitiam, quorum adventu intendebantur eculei uncosque parabat carnifex et tormenta. et ex is proscripti sunt plures actique in exilium alii, non nullos gladii consumpsere poenales. nec enim quisquam facile meminit sub Constantio, ubi susurro tenus haec movebantur, quemquam absolutum.

Quare talis improborum consensio non modo excusatione amicitiae tegenda non est sed potius supplicio omni vindicanda est, ut ne quis concessum putet amicum vel bellum patriae inferentem sequi; quod quidem, ut res ire coepit, haud scio an aliquando futurum sit. Mihi autem non minori curae est, qualis res publica post mortem meam futura, quam qualis hodie sit.
            
            Quid? qui se etiam nunc subsidiis patrimonii aut amicorum liberalitate sustentant, hos perire patiemur? An, si qui frui publico non potuit per hostem, hic tegitur ipsa lege censoria; quem is frui non sinit, qui est, etiamsi non appellatur, hostis, huic ferri auxilium non oportet? Retinete igitur in provincia diutius eum, qui de sociis cum hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.

Quam ob rem id primum videamus, si placet, quatenus amor in amicitia progredi debeat. Numne, si Coriolanus habuit amicos, ferre contra patriam arma illi cum Coriolano debuerunt? num Vecellinum amici regnum adpetentem, num Maelium debuerunt iuvare?

Vita est illis semper in fuga uxoresque mercenariae conductae ad tempus ex pacto atque, ut sit species matrimonii, dotis nomine futura coniunx hastam et tabernaculum offert marito, post statum diem si id elegerit discessura, et incredibile est quo ardore apud eos in venerem uterque solvitur sexus.

Quibus ita sceleste patratis Paulus cruore perfusus reversusque ad principis castra multos coopertos paene catenis adduxit in squalorem deiectos atque maestitiam, quorum adventu intendebantur eculei uncosque parabat carnifex et tormenta. et ex is proscripti sunt plures actique in exilium alii, non nullos gladii consumpsere poenales. nec enim quisquam facile meminit sub Constantio, ubi susurro tenus haec movebantur, quemquam absolutum.

Quare talis improborum consensio non modo excusatione amicitiae tegenda non est sed potius supplicio omni vindicanda est, ut ne quis concessum putet amicum vel bellum patriae inferentem sequi; quod quidem, ut res ire coepit, haud scio an aliquando futurum sit. Mihi autem non minori curae est, qualis res publica post mortem meam futura, quam qualis hodie sit.
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
            <hr />
            Heyy
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gap"></div>
        <div class="right-column">
          <div class="header">
            Column B
            <hr />
          </div>
          <div class="non-scrollable">
            Quid? qui se etiam nunc subsidiis patrimonii aut amicorum liberalitate sustentant, hos perire patiemur? An, si qui frui publico non potuit per hostem, hic tegitur ipsa lege censoria; quem is frui non sinit, qui est, etiamsi non appellatur, hostis, huic ferri auxilium non oportet? Retinete igitur in provincia diutius eum, qui de sociis cum hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.

Quam ob rem id primum videamus, si placet, quatenus amor in amicitia progredi debeat. Numne, si Coriolanus habuit amicos, ferre contra patriam arma illi cum Coriolano debuerunt? num Vecellinum amici regnum adpetentem, num Maelium debuerunt iuvare?

Vita est illis semper in fuga uxoresque mercenariae conductae ad tempus ex pacto atque, ut sit species matrimonii, dotis nomine futura coniunx hastam et tabernaculum offert marito, post statum diem si id elegerit discessura, et incredibile est quo ardore apud eos in venerem uterque solvitur sexus.

Quibus ita sceleste patratis Paulus cruore perfusus reversusque ad principis castra multos coopertos paene catenis adduxit in squalorem deiectos atque maestitiam, quorum adventu intendebantur eculei uncosque parabat carnifex et tormenta. et ex is proscripti sunt plures actique in exilium alii, non nullos gladii consumpsere poenales. nec enim quisquam facile meminit sub Constantio, ubi susurro tenus haec movebantur, quemquam absolutum.

Quare talis improborum consensio non modo excusatione amicitiae tegenda non est sed potius supplicio omni vindicanda est, ut ne quis concessum putet amicum vel bellum patriae inferentem sequi; quod quidem, ut res ire coepit, haud scio an aliquando futurum sit. Mihi autem non minori curae est, qualis res publica post mortem meam futura, quam qualis hodie sit.
            
            Quid? qui se etiam nunc subsidiis patrimonii aut amicorum liberalitate sustentant, hos perire patiemur? An, si qui frui publico non potuit per hostem, hic tegitur ipsa lege censoria; quem is frui non sinit, qui est, etiamsi non appellatur, hostis, huic ferri auxilium non oportet? Retinete igitur in provincia diutius eum, qui de sociis cum hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.

Quam ob rem id primum videamus, si placet, quatenus amor in amicitia progredi debeat. Numne, si Coriolanus habuit amicos, ferre contra patriam arma illi cum Coriolano debuerunt? num Vecellinum amici regnum adpetentem, num Maelium debuerunt iuvare?

Vita est illis semper in fuga uxoresque mercenariae conductae ad tempus ex pacto atque, ut sit species matrimonii, dotis nomine futura coniunx hastam et tabernaculum offert marito, post statum diem si id elegerit discessura, et incredibile est quo ardore apud eos in venerem uterque solvitur sexus.

Quibus ita sceleste patratis Paulus cruore perfusus reversusque ad principis castra multos coopertos paene catenis adduxit in squalorem deiectos atque maestitiam, quorum adventu intendebantur eculei uncosque parabat carnifex et tormenta. et ex is proscripti sunt plures actique in exilium alii, non nullos gladii consumpsere poenales. nec enim quisquam facile meminit sub Constantio, ubi susurro tenus haec movebantur, quemquam absolutum.

Quare talis improborum consensio non modo excusatione amicitiae tegenda non est sed potius supplicio omni vindicanda est, ut ne quis concessum putet amicum vel bellum patriae inferentem sequi; quod quidem, ut res ire coepit, haud scio an aliquando futurum sit. Mihi autem non minori curae est, qualis res publica post mortem meam futura, quam qualis hodie sit.
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
            <hr />
            Heyy
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> As a side note: Do not try to use display:flex in each element. Only in parents is enough. Otherwise, it will cause chaos.

Comment: Hey, thanks but the point was to keep the columns scrollable in the first codepen, and that's not it

Comment: I edited the question so that it's clearer. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Yeah but the point is to have the same CSS for the base of the page. it is in the requirements

Comment: So, additional classes can be createad, is it?

Comment: Actually that wouldn't be a problem, but I need to have the same foundation on both layouts