# flex-wrap: nowrap width doesn't include children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Shouldn't a flexbox with `flex-wrap: nowrap` naturally be the width of it's children?

For some reason, it's only the width of its parent. Is it possible to make it get the width of its children?

In [this codepen](https://codepen.io/robgordon/pen/NJyzwR) you can see that the background doesn't extend the full width of all the children.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.flex div {
  flex-basis: 75%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I used *"should"* under the assumption that a typical div with `white-space: nowrap` applied to inline children would grow to accommodate its children; however, that doesn't appear to be true either (https://codepen.io/robgordon/pen/gEvjpL).

Comment: Flexbox is just a layout context for the children. It doesn't change the element properties of the wrapper. Essentially you're giving the children sizes/layouts that force them to `overflow` the container but the container is constrained by its parent.

Comment: The `background-color` doesn't work that way. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45497031/3597276

Comment: applying `inline-flex` alone isn't a solution for this particular case because flex-basis is used with percetange, so the solution/explanation involve more than a simple `inline-flex` thus it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element is a block element which means that its width is 100% of its containing block width and in this case it's the body element.

Add border to the body element to better see:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.flex div {
  flex-basis: 75%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

body {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>
```

Same think for the body element if you add border to html since this one is also a block element:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.flex div {
  flex-basis: 75%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

body {
  border:2px solid green;
}
html {
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>
```

So all your element are restriced by your screen size. From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth) we have this rule:

```
'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block
```

Since we have no padding/margin/border we will have `width = width of containing block`.

This logic apply to all our elements until we reach the viewport:

> The containing block in which the **root element lives** is a rectangle called the initial containing block. For continuous media, it has **the dimensions of the viewport** and is anchored at the canvas origin; it is the page area for paged media. The 'direction' property of the initial containing block is the same as for the root element.

---

Also in your case, there is no way to contain all the elements simply because your are defining the width of your elements using a percetange that will (in all the cases) be bigger than the parent. You have `4*75%` that is always bigger than `100%`.

So whataver you will do you will always have an overflow:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.flex div {
  flex-basis: 75%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

body {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex" style="display:inline-flex">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>

<div class="flex" style="width:50%;">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>

<div class="flex" style="width:500%;">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>

<div class="flex" style="width:200px;">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>
```

But in case the width are defined using pixel for example (let's consider 500px) Then the parent element may contain its child with the `inline-flex` setting.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.flex div {
  width: 500px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

body {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex" style="display:inline-flex">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>

<div class="flex" >
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>
```

In this case the width is a *shrink-to-fit* width described as below:

> Calculation of the shrink-to-fit width is similar to calculating the width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm. Roughly: calculate the preferred width by formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur, and also calculate the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks. CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm. Thirdly, find the available width: in this case, this is the width of the containing block minus the used values of 'margin-left', 'border-left-width', 'padding-left', 'padding-right', 'border-right-width', 'margin-right', and the widths of any relevant scroll bars.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: `min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width).`

---

Note that using `flex-basis` with pixel value won't give the same result as `width`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.flex div {
  flex-basis: 500px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

body {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex" style="display:inline-flex">
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>

<div class="flex" >
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
  <div>hi</div>
</div>
```

More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/8620333

<sup>`nowrap` is the default value of `flex-wrap` so it can be omitted in the below examples</sup>