# Flex child does not take width of it's own children and cuts off hover

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For some reason my complete understanding from CSS has been broken by the following snippet. My goal here is to show a hover over the whole `.some-row-with-items` element when I hover over it. For some reason unbeknownst to me, it cuts off the element right at the position of the scrollbar though and doesn't extend to cover all elements even though no explicit width is set. This is apparent by the red border added for visibility when you scroll horizontally.

Question here now is, how can I achieve a full hover over the full row?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.flex-main-content {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.some-long-row-with-items {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.some-long-row-with-items:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.some-item {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-main">
  <div class="flex-main-content">
    <div class="nonflex">
      <div class="some-long-row-with-items">
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `inline-flex` on some-long-row-with-items ?

Comment: did you try setting width on .some-long-row-with-items to fit-content ?

Comment: @mocni_T Setting a width would mean the row is no longer flexible and it would defeat the purpose.

Comment: The problem is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45497031/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an *inline container* by using `display: inline-flex`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.flex-main-content {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.some-long-row-with-items {
  display: inline-flex; /* change here */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.some-long-row-with-items:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.some-item {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-main">
  <div class="flex-main-content">
    <div class="nonflex">
      <div class="some-long-row-with-items">
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `width: max-content` on the *flexbox container*:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.flex-main-content {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.some-long-row-with-items {
  display: flex; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: max-content; /* added */
}

.some-long-row-with-items:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.some-item {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-main">
  <div class="flex-main-content">
    <div class="nonflex">
      <div class="some-long-row-with-items">
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
        <div class="some-item"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `flexbox` takes up the width of its container, which in this case is `100%` or `100vw`. So when you apply hover effect on the `.some-long-row-with-items`, it causes background change over that amount of width. 
 `flex: 0 0 50px` style applied to `.some-item` makes the child elements take up the width of 50px, which would otherwise be auto. This is why the content inside the `flexbox` is overflowing out of it.
You can avoid this situation by:

- setting `width: max-content` to the parent of the flexbox
- setting `width: max-content` to flexbox
- setting `overflow: hidden` to `.some-long-row-with-items`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and apparently if you just remove `flex: 0 0 50px;` from your class `.some-item` works perfect, if I understand what you mean.

Comment: This apparently doesn't work as it will result in the items shrinking to fit. The items need to stay the same size. I tried setting `flex-shrink: 0` to see if it helps but the problem persists.

Comment: Removing `flex: 0 0 50px;` they just center themselves and the shrinking it's almost imperceptible, sad it didn't work well