# HTML Scrollbar on a <ul>

Tags: html, css

I have a List, and I want to set a static maximum height on each item of the list and show a scrollbar when the text overflows it: I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    @foreach(var item in List)
    {
        <li>
            <a />
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

**CSS** (I have more styles, but for the sake of exemplifying, I posted only the relevant ones)

```
ul, li
{
    overflow-y:auto;
}

ul li a
{
    background: #ffc;
    display: block;
    height: 08em;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

The background color will only apply for the defined height. So how can I resolve it? I assume by envolving `<li>` on another tag and applying the styles to that tag instead, but I'm not sure how to apply that

**Edit**
I would like to point to the answer of Michael Benjamin on [Make background color extend into overflow area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497031/make-background-color-extend-into-overflow-area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you applied the `background-color` to your `<a>` element, not your `<li>`

```css
ul li {
max-height : 100px;
overflow-y : auto;
background-color : yellow;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) {
background-color : red; /* for example purpose only */
}

ul li a {
     writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* for example purpose only */
     text-orientation: mixed; /* for example purpose only */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> <a> Very long item that willd force a vertical scroll </a> </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> Item </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was applying the overflow-y to `<a />` (applying the styles to the `<li />` doesn´t work that well in my current program), but this pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `li` to be on a specific heigh and want the inner content to be scroll. Then Provide the height to `li` and give `overflow-y: auto`

So your code should be like this

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height: 8rem;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```