# Sticky header when horizontal overflow of content

Tags: html, css

In my HTML page I have main header and body and inside the body there is another header and body - this body overflows horizontally.

What I need is not to display white space on the right side of both headers, when the inner body scrollbar is moved right, but to "move" both headers as well.

I have found a solution how to "fill" this space in main header by setting

```
position: sticky; 
left: 0;
```

on that, but I cannot find a way how to do the same with the inner header.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1uda0ksz/2/) of the situation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this is basically pretty much the same situation as https://stackoverflow.com/q/45497031/1427878, only on the other axis.

Answer (score 0):

Frimlink I checked your code, and the `width` property in the `.body` element is not set. `.inner-header` and `.inner-body` are child elements whose sizes are determined by the parent element. if the parent element's width property is empty.

The solution is to add `width: fit-content;` to the ".body" element.

```
.body {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: My original question did not contain one important part: There are some controls in both headers, so I need to "move" the headers along with the scrollbar. I updated the fiddle. If these controls had not been, you answer would have been perfect...

Comment: If you are adding any controls then is also scrolling a controls and header along with scrollbar.